# A program to change my C/GTK+ code to comply with GEdit's standards

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I'm going to be making changes to my version of GEdit. I would also like to submit some of my code to the actual GEdit team (bug fixes and stuff like that). GEdit uses a standard to format code like so:

```
static void hello( GtkWidget *widget,
                   gpointer   data )
{
    g_print ("Hello World\n");
}
```

Which I forget (can't stand) to use. I format my code like so:

```
static void hello(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    g_print("Hello World\n");
}
```

I was just wondering if there was a program that I could run on my code that would format my code to comply to GEdit's standards?

Comment: I hope your bugfixes get through :-)

Comment: Thanks. I also would like to see if they will add my syntax highlighting for GTK types like GtkWidget. It would be pretty sweet.

Comment: That would be very useful. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think GNU indent (http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) is what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much! This will be a big help!